# Tableview delegate not return value

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

i have problem with *UIButton* cancel of *tableviewcontroller*, when I do test, and I click the cancel button to call the action, he did not call the delegate, not work, follow code.

**StalkViewController**.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FMDBDataAccess.h"
#import "EditStalkViewController.h"
#import "NewStalkViewController.h"

@interface StalkViewController : UITableViewController<NewStalkViewControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *stalks;
-(void)populateStalk;

@end
```

**StalkViewController.m**

```
-(void) addNewStalkViewControllerDidCancel:(NewStalkViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"addStalk"])
    {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        NewStalkViewController *addNewStalkViewController = (NewStalkViewController *)[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
        addNewStalkViewController.delegate = self;

    }
}
```

**NewStalkViewController.h**

```
#import "Stalk.h"
#import "Utility.h"

@class NewStalkViewController;

@protocol NewStalkViewControllerDelegate<NSObject>


-(void) addNewStalkViewControllerDidCancel:(NewStalkViewController *)controller;

@end

@interface NewStalkViewController : UITableViewController<FBFriendPickerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>
{
}

@property (nonatomic,weak) id<NewStalkViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;

@end
```

**NewStalkViewController.m**

```
#import "NewStalkViewController.h"

@implementation NewStalkViewController

@synthesize delegate;

-(IBAction)cancel:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate addNewStalkViewControllerDidCancel:self];
}

@end
```

help me!!

Comment: This might causing with your Navigation Stack . Try this **NewStalkViewController *addNewStalkViewController = [self.Storyboard instantiateviewcontrollerwithidentifier:@""];**

Comment: Is your UIButton properly connected to the action in your storyboard?

Comment: no work with self storyboard :(

Comment: Yes UIButton connected with action